# Wifi speed very slow, iwlwifi problems

Tags: networking, wireless

I never noticed it until I upgraded to fiber. My phone pulls up to 400MBPS but my ubuntu is 150MBPS ish max. I read a (hell) lot of methods and issues and they increased my speed from 50 MBPS to what it is now.

At first, the wifi link speed was at 50 MBPS max but once I removed power saver and fixed a bug in avahi the link speed went to 477 MBPS, however internet speed (speedtest.net) is not as fast as my phone.

An ethernet cable pulls the same speed as my android, the problem is definetely wifi. Here are some problems I found :

```
Sep 24 11:42:11 -G3-3579 kernel: [    3.578600] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Sep 24 11:42:11 -G3-3579 kernel: [    3.624291] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 43.95eb4e97.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Sep 24 11:42:11 -G3-3579 kernel: [    3.677257] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9462, REV=0x318
Sep 24 11:42:11 -G3-3579 kernel: [    3.726205] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: a0:a4:c5:4c:43:f2
Sep 24 11:42:11 -G3-3579 kernel: [    4.245506] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
Sep 24 11:42:11 -G3-3579 NetworkManager[1003]: <info>  [1569318131.8016] rfkill1: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill1) (driver iwlwifi)
Sep 24 11:42:12 -G3-3579 kernel: [    6.359459] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Conflict between TLV & NVM regarding enabling LAR (TLV = enabled NVM =disabled)
Sep 24 11:42:12 -G3-3579 kernel: [    6.363953] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
Sep 24 11:51:02 -G3-3579 NetworkManager[4508]: <info>  [1569318662.1277] rfkill1: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill1) (driver iwlwifi)
Sep 24 11:51:02 -G3-3579 kernel: [  535.921835] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Conflict between TLV & NVM regarding enabling LAR (TLV = enabled NVM =disabled)
Sep 24 11:51:02 -G3-3579 kernel: [  535.930619] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS



lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] [8086:a370] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:42a4]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Here's the guide I followed :
https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/

I'm on 18.04

Comment: Same here with ....    03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 [8086:2526] (rev 29)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4010]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi

Comment: It seems that Ubuntu is keeping its tradition of breaking things with updates.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same exact Intel Wi-Fi module and this fixed the issue.

Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and add the following at the end of the file
`options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0`

Then do `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi` and `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`
Or just reboot.